# Angularjs Custom Directive Not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I had created one custom directive for emded tag to use src . It is working for mozilla firefox but not working in chrome.

```
app.directive('embedSrc', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function() {
              return attrs.embedSrc;
            },
            function() {
              element.attr('src', attrs.embedSrc);
            }
          );
        }
      };
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: may be try `attrs.$observe('embedSrc', .... )`

Comment: create a plunkr with the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

and

```
attrs.$observe('embedSrc', function (newValue) {
    newValue === "true";
});
```

Comment: your answer makes no sense.